# \mathcal doesn't have the usual output

Tags: mathcal

I used these commands in order to have along with the \mathcal{L} a calligraphic L as well

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{calrsfs}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\pazocal}{OMS}{zplm}{m}{n}
\newcommand{\La}{\mathcal{L}}
\newcommand{\Lb}{\pazocal{L}}

\begin{document}
$\La \Lb$
\end{document}
```

but now the other letters with \mathcal are not what they supposed to be.
My question is, therefore, how can I keep using the \La,\Lb commands for the two L's and at the same time have the usual output of \mathcal for other letters, take \mathcal{O} for example.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  It would help greatly if you could extend your code to be compilable, starting with `\documentclass`.  Since font selection is affected greatly by the class, that will give potential helpers a realistic example that they can experiment with.

Comment: If you want to use two different script or calligraphic alphabets, the simplest way to do so is to load one as `\mathcal` and the other as `\mathscr` with the `mathallpha` package.

Comment: If you want to use *three* calligraphic alphabets in the same paper? Stop and consider whether that’s really a good idea. You did? Okay. Replace `\usepackage{calrsfs}` with another math alphabet definition, similar to the one you used for `\pazocal`. Be aware that you have only a limited number of math alphabets, unless you switch to `unicode-math`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\mathcal` is automatically assigned to the reference package `calrsfs` (I think). If you want the classic `\mathcal`, you can use `\pazocal` instead of `\mathcal` as in the example below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{calrsfs}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\pazocal}{OMS}{zplm}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet\pazocal{bold}{OMS}{zplm}{bx}{n}
\newcommand{\mth}{\mathcal{A}}
\newcommand{\pzc}{\pazocal{A}}

\begin{document}
$\mathcal{A}$, $\pazocal{A},\boldsymbol{\pazocal{A}}$, $\mth,\pzc$
\end{document}
```